# Find and remove from the string words beginning with the letter A

Tags: php

Suppose I have a string and want to remove all the words that begin with the letter ***a*** or ***A***.:

```
$string = 'Aorem ipsum adolor sit amet, consectetur dipiscing aelit.';
```

That's how I was thinking:

```
$words = explode(' ', $string);
    foreach ($words as $wordA) {
    if ($wordA ***starts with letter*** 'a' OR 'A') {
```

How to write the statement  **if ($wordA starts with letter a OR A)** and then to remove those words from the string (maybe something like **$stringB = preg_replace($wordA, ' ', $string);** )? Or do otherwise?

Thanks!

Comment: `echo preg_replace('/\bA\w+\b/i', '', $string);`

Comment: Or even to don't add space befoe commas and points `echo preg_replace('/\s*A\w+\b/i', '', $string);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use like

```
$string = 'Aorem ipsum adolor sit amet, consectetur dipiscing aelit.';
echo "<br>".preg_replace('/(\ba\w+\b|\bA\w+\b)/', '', $string);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ipsum sit , consectetur dipiscing .
```